# jQuery autocomplete trouble in selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This is my code for jQuery autocomplete searchbox, in source I am pushing array of JSON objects like `[{displayName :'john',value:'12345',email:'john@gmail.com'},...]`

```
 var termTemplate = "<span class='ui-autocomplete-term'>%s</span>";
    $('.searchboxx').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            response($.grep(contacts, function(contact) {
                return matcher.test(contact.displayName)
                        || matcher.test(contact.value) || matcher.test(contact.email);
            }));
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var contact = ui.item;

        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, contact) {
        return $("<li>")
                .append('<a><div class="row">' +
                contact.displayName + " <" + contact.value + ">" + " [" + contact.rel + "]" +
                '</div>' +
                '</div></a>')
                .appendTo(ul);
    };
```

my ul is like `<li>john<12345>[mobile]</li>,.....` when I clicked on one of them than, i am getting 12345 in search box but I want name appear at searchbox, how can i achive that?
I tried by adding a peace of code in select

```
if(ui.item){
                    $('.searchboxx').val(contact.displayName);
                }
```

but it is not working any suggestions?

Comment: what does `response()` do? Arent u supposed to be assigning that a variable and using it later in your `select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array passed to the `response` callback from `source` normally contains objects with properties `label` (displayed in dropdown) and `value` (inserted into input element). The `value` property of your contact objects is their ID, so that's what gets inserted.

To insert the name of the contact you need to override the `select` event, for example

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    $(event.target).val(ui.item.displayName);
    return false;
}
```

To also display the name on keyboard navigation you need to similarly override `focus`.

An alternative solution is to give `response` an array of objects with properties `{ label: contact, value: contact.displayName }`. The default handlers for the events `select` and `focus` will then work correctly, and only `_renderItem` has to be modified slightly. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ67m/.